# How to make sure if an `OpenException` from POI is related to Zip Bomb and not other opening issues

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi, try-catch

I am trying to load an `.xlsx` file Using POI, and I get an `OpenException` in my try catch block. How can I find out what is the exact reason of it from exception to handle it differently. for example my case is a zip bomb
but it might be a corrupted file or any other reason that I want to handle differently and show different messages.

This question is also related: [*Using apache poi—Zip Bomb detected*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897500/using-apache-poi-zip-bomb-detected); but I want to make sure that it was a zip bomb and then handle it and not directly assume it is a zip bomb.