# NIFI excel file

Tags: excel, apache-nifi

I have an Excel file that has several sheets. Preprocessor Convertexcelto CSV processor can not convey it. How to solve this error?

> ```
>  org.apache.nifi.processors.poi.ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor.error
>     IOException thrown from ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor[id=a0aa3e82-1d3c-18c0-b1a7-b9d4429d5958]:
> ```
>
> java.io.IOException: Zip bomb detected! The file would exceed the max.
> ratio of compressed file size to the size of the expanded data. This
> may indicate that the file is used to inflate memory usage and thus
> could pose a security risk. You can adjust this limit via
> ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio() if you need to work with files
> which exceed this limit. Uncompressed size: 358510, Raw/compressed
> size: 3584, ratio: 0.009997 Limits: MIN_INFLATE_RATIO: 0.010000,
> Entry: xl/styles.xml

Comment: Did you read the error message? Have you checked the source? Does it open in Excel, since you say it is an Excel file? Have you tried saving as a flat file? Or csv?

Comment: This is an Apache POI safeguard, which NiFI uses to interact with XML. Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897500/using-apache-poi-zip-bomb-detected